# java script clock matter can't find yet

Tags: javascript

I'm making chrome clone for website about clock. But I got some problem.
I've tried to do of putting on my code following on js code on online class
I don't know why can't see my clock. just showing me 00:00 on web.
How can I solve it to be smart?

※I've considered what problem is there. but I couldn't find out.

```
  const clockContainer = document.querySelector(".js-clock"),
  clockTitle = clockContainer.querySelector("h1");
function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  clockTitle.innerText = `${hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours}:${
    minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes
  }:${seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`;
}

function init() {
  getTime();
  setInterval(getTime, 1000);
}

init();
```

here's my github
https://github.com/fatejin/js-chrome.clone.git

[image: this is my error about java script clock error]

Comment: Information that is essential to the question should be embedded in your question, not behind a link. As it turns out you made a typo, so I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is;

```
<script scr="clock.js"></script>
```

must be

```
<script src="clock.js"></script>
```

Not scr, must be src

Comment: thank you for that. what a idot. it is just simple matter. ;

Answer (score -1):

The code in the repo doesn't have correct src in the script tag. Here is the working code.

```js
const clockContainer = document.querySelector(".js-clock"),
clockTitle = clockContainer.querySelector("h1");

function getTime() {
  const date = new Date();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  clockTitle.innerText = `${hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours}:${
    minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes
  }:${seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`;
}

function init() {
  getTime();
  setInterval(getTime, 1000);
}

init()

The script tag didn't have `src` in your repo. Here is a working code.
```

```html
<div class="js-clock">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```